# Integer verification and sum till it in js

Tags: javascript, integer

```
var a = prompt("Please write an integer number greater than 0");
while ((a <= 0) || (Math.round(a) != a)) {
    alert("Number that you have wrote is wrong, please write another one.");
    var a = prompt("Please write an integer number greater than 0");
};
var i;
var sum;
for (i = 0; i <= a; i++){
    var s = sum += i;
};
    document.write("your sum till your number is = " + s);
```

I've tried to ask user to write an integer greater than 0 and after that to write on the screen Sum till that number, but there is something wrong with the answer which is like that << your sum till your number is = NaN >>; 
Can someone help me with that error. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you have `s` as well as `sum`? One or the other is enough, but you have to initialise it to `0` before you start adding to it (otherwise it is `undefined`, and `undefined + 0` is `NaN`, and `NaN + 1` is `NaN`, etc.).

Comment: that's because I've tried different ways but neither was good, and I forgot to erase << var s ...>>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Declare `var sum = 0;`
2. In your loop, execute `sum += i;`

**Example:**

```js
var a = prompt("Please write an integer number greater than 0");

while ((a <= 0) || (Math.round(a) != a)) {
    alert("Number that you have wrote is wrong, please write another one.");
    var a = prompt("Please write an integer number greater than 0");
}

var i;
var sum = 0;

for (i = 0; i <= a; i++){
    sum += i;
};
    document.write("your sum till your number is = " + sum);
```